# How output a json file in postgresql functions?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, copy

I want to define a trigger in postgresql when updated a record in a db table, It output the record as a json file:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   id serial primary key,
   first_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
   last_name varchar(40) NOT NULL
);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myFunction() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

     // My Code

     RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON mytable 
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE myFunction();
```

How can I do it?

Comment: trigger functions return record - they do not output. unles s you want to raise to stdout. please disclose tables structure, some data sample and desired result in code

Comment: @VaoTsun I updated it.

Comment: I need json file to import another project.

Comment: so you want trigger dfunction to generate json file for you?..

Comment: Yes I need to generate json file in trigger function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// My Code

change to smth like:

```
 execute format($f$copy (select %L) to '/tmp/f.json'$f$,row_to_json(NEW));
```

but it will require either SU or `SECURITY DEFINER` function. Also `for each row` trigger will rewrite the file as many times as many rows you update in one statement...

Instead I would use CTE, eg:

```
with u as (update mytable set.. returning *)
select to_json(u) from u
```

saving result to somewhere in application, not server FS